# Project Euler getting smallest multiple in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing problem five in Project Euler: "2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"

I have constructed the following code which finds the correct value 2520 when using 1 - 10 as divisors but code seems to be going on forever when using 1 - 20.
Again I don't  want the code just a pointer or two on where I am going wrong.
Thanks

```
def smallestDiv(n):
    end=False
    while end == False:
        divisors = [x for x in range(1,21)]    # get divisors
        allDivisions = zip(n % i for i in divisors)    # get values for  n % all integers in divisors
        check = all(item[0]  == 0 for item in allDivisions )   # check if all values of n % i are equal to zero
        if check:         # if all values are equal to zero return n
            end = True
            return n
        else:             # else increase n by 1
            n +=1
```

EDIT:

I used some code I found relating to LCM  and used reduce to solve the problem:

```
def lcm(*values):
    values = [value for value in values]
    if values:
        n  = max(values)
        m = n
        values.remove(n)
        while any( n % value for value in values ):
            n +=m
        return n
    return 0

print reduce(lcm, range(1,21))
```

Comment: 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19. >>> 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
232792560

Comment: @hughdbrown could you explain that further?

Comment: @hughdbrown is this related to Fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Comment: You need to divide by all numbers from 1 to 20, so you need a collection of the prime factors. The primes in that range are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, and 19. You need four 2's to divide 16 and two 3's for 9 and 18. If you select from the resulting list, you can find the prime factors for all the numbers 20 and under.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If a problem is hard, trying solving a simpler version. Here, how to calculate the lowest common multiple of *two* numbers. If you've read any number theory book (or think about prime factors), you can do that using the greatest common divisor function (as implemented by the Euclidean algorithm).

```
from fractions import gcd
def lcm(a,b):
    "Calculate the lowest common multiple of two integers a and b"
    return a*b//gcd(a,b)
```

Observing `lcm(a,b,c) ≡ lcm(lcm(a,b),c)` it's simple to solve your problem with Python's [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lcm, range(1,10+1))
2520
>>> reduce(lcm, range(1,20+1))
232792560
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. It's really short and works. My answer is clumsy by comparison.

Comment: @Colonel panic, Thanks, I added a function `def allLcms(*args):`                 ``return reduce(lcm1, args)`

Comment: @Colonel panic, sorry, I could not edit previous comment. Thanks for your help, I solved it using your advice.

Comment: I'm not fulling grasping the last bit. Reduce will apply the lcm function use the range from 1 to 20, starting with 1, 2 then 2, 3 then 3, 4 etc. The sum of all that calculated lcm() is the answer, is that it? I'm confused.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing a brute force search, so it can get arbitrary long. You should read about LCM (least common multiple) in order to code an efficient solution.(which I believe is `232792560`)

Comment: I improved my code my increasing i by 20 each time  and got the correct answer but still trying to figure out an alternative method.

Answer (score 2):

```
int gcd(int m, int n)
{
    int t;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        t=n;
        n=m%n;
        m=t;
    }
    return m;
}

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int long long lcm=1;
    printf("Enter the range:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        lcm = (i*lcm)/gcd(i,lcm);
    }
    printf("smallest multiple : %uL",lcm);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the factors in the numbers from 1 to 20:

```
from collections import Counter

def prime_factors(x):
    def factor_this(x, factor):
        factors = []
        while x % factor == 0:
            x /= factor
            factors.append(factor)
        return x, factors
    x, factors = factor_this(x, 2)
    x, f = factor_this(x, 3)
    factors += f
    i = 5
    while i * i <= x:
        for j in (2, 4):
            x, f = factor_this(x, i)
            factors += f
            i += j
    if x > 1:
        factors.append(x)
    return factors

def factors_in_range(x):
    result = {}
    for i in range(2, x + 1):
        p = prime_factors(i)
        c = Counter(p)
        for k, v in c.items():
            n = result.get(k)
            if n is None or n < v:
                result[k] = v
    return result

print factors_in_range(20)
```

If you multiply these numbers together, as many times as they occur in the result, you get the smallest number that divides all the numbers from 1 to 20.

```
import operator

def product(c):
    return reduce(operator.__mul__, [k ** v for k, v in c.items()], 1)

c = factors_in_range(20)
print product(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer by Colonel Panic is brilliant but I just wanted to expand on it a little bit without editing the concise answer.

The original solution is:

```
from fractions import gcd
def lcm(a,b):
    "Calculate the lowest common multiple of two integers a and b"
    return a*b//gcd(a,b)

>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lcm, range(1,10+1))
2520
>>> reduce(lcm, range(1,20+1))
232792560
```

I find it helpful to visualize what the reduce is doing for N = 10:

```
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(1, 2), 3), 4), 5), 6), 7), 8), 9), 10)
```

Which evaluates to:

```
# Evaluates lcm(1, 2)
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(1, 2), 3), 4), 5), 6), 7), 8), 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(2, 3)
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(2, 3), 4), 5), 6), 7), 8), 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(6, 4)
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(6, 4), 5), 6), 7), 8), 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(12, 5)
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(12, 5), 6), 7), 8), 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(60, 6)
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(60, 6), 7), 8), 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(60, 7)
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(lcm(60, 7), 8), 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(420, 8)
res = lcm(lcm(lcm(420, 8), 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(840, 9)
res = lcm(lcm(840, 9), 10)
# Evaluates lcm(2520, 10)
res = lcm(2520, 10)

print(res)
>>> 2520
```

The above gets across the intuition of what is happening. When we use reduce we "apply a rolling computation to sequential pairs of values in a list." It does this from the "inside-out" or from the left to the right in `range(1, 20+1)`.

I think it is really important here to point out that you, as a programmer, are NOT expected to intuit this answer as being obvious or readily apparent. It has taken a lot of smart people a long time to learn a great deal about prime numbers, greatest common factors, and least common multiples, etc. **However, as a software engineer you ARE expected to know the basics about number theory, gcd, lcm, prime numbers, and how to solve problems with these in your toolkit.** Again, you are not expected to re-invent the wheel or re-discover things from number theory each time you solve a problem, but as you go about your business you should be adding tools to your problem solving toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def smallestDiv(n):
    divisors = [x for x in range(1,(n+1))]    # get divisors
    for i in xrange(2520,sys.maxint,n):
        if(all(i%x == 0 for x in divisors)):
            return i

print (smallestDiv(20))
```

Takes approximately 5 seconds on my 1.7 GHZ i7

I based it on the C# code here:
http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-5/

Comment: what does sys.maxint do? I have looked it up in the docs but it is still unclear to me.

Comment: It provides the maximum integer value available.  xrange() as opposed to range() will ensure you don't actually create a range that goes all the way to it!

Comment: Thanks, so xrange acts like  a generator?

Answer (score 0):

```
facList=[2]
prod=1

for i in range(3,1000):
    n=i
    for j in facList:
        if n % j == 0:
            n//=j
    facList.append(n)

for k in facList:
prod*=k

print(prod)
```

I tried this method and compared my time to Colonel Panic's answer and mine started significantly beating his at about n=200 instead of n=20. His is much more elegant in my opinion, but for some reason mine is faster. Maybe someone with better understanding of algorithm runtime can explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Last function finds the smallest number dividable by n, since the number should be multiples of factorial(n), you need to have a function that calculates factorial (can be done via math. method)

```
def factoral(n):
    if n > 1:
        return n * factoral(n - 1)
    elif n >= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def isMultiple(a, b):
    for i in range(1, b):
        if a % i != 0:
            return False
    return True

def EnkucukBul(n):
    for i in range(n, factoral(n) + 1, n):
        if isMultiple(i, n):
            return i
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use math module, you can use math.lcm

```py
import math
def smallestMul():
    return(math.lcm(1, 2, 3, ..., 20))
```

Comment: Your answer does not address the actual question.